# Error: spawn git ENOENT on Windows 7

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, child-process, spawn

- **Node.js Version**: v10.7.0
- **OS**: Windows 7 x64
- **Scope**: runtime
- **Module**: child_process

I was using a script I made which was working fine and for some reason now I get the following error.
[image]
Though, I'm not sure if this error is due to node, git or something else but it seems to come from node since I can run git from anywhere in my computer and the returned signal is ENOENT which I believe means it didn't find git.

The only thing I've done since the last time my script worked is updating node to the latest version (v10.7.0).

[Linked issue on Github](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/1397)